# Order of Evaluation for Multiple Join Constraints

Tags: sql-server, join

If a query contains a join with multiple join constraints, are the constraints evaluated in left to right order or does SQL Server decide the optimum way to evaluate them?

In hopes of clarifying, I'll try to explain why I'm asking.  Let's say I have a table named **Alpha** and it has two columns in addition to a standard ID.  The first column is named **Generic1** and is a varchar(20). The second is named **Type** and is a **smallint**.  If **Type = 1** then the value of **Generic1** will actually be the **ID** of a record in another table (lets call it **Bravo**).  If **Type = 2** then the value of **Generic1** will be some plain text value.

I want to write the following query:

```
select * from Beta b
left outer join Alpha a on a.Type = 1 and a.Generic1 = b.ID
```

If I can safely assume that SQL Server will only attempt the comparison of **a.Generic1 = b.ID** AFTER it has compared **a.Type = 1**, then I don't have to worry about cast/conversion errors.  I would like the SQL to avoid using syntax that is only valid in SQL Server if possible.

I'm guessing that SQL Server evaluates them as it sees fit, so I'll have to add a **CAST** to be safe.

Comment: Why do you have a mixed column like this? Sounds like there should be a FK relationship to `Bravo` which at the moment presumably you have no way of enforcing.

Comment: agreed this is a normalization problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I expected some comments about the relationships, but unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have a mixed column like this? Sounds like there should be a FK relationship to `Bravo` which at the moment presumably you have no way of enforcing.

Anyway assuming you are stuck with this schema no order of evaluation is guaranteed in SQL Server. You would need to do something like

```
... ON a.Type = 1 AND CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(a.Generic1) = 1 
                    THEN a.Generic1 END = b.ID 
        /* Result of "CASE" implicitly cast to int*/
```

(Though you might want to use a method [specifically for integers](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) instead though as `isnumeric` does not guarantee that a value will successfully cast to `int`)

Answer (score 2):

1) Never ever depend on the execution plan to insure that mismatched datatypes will match up.

2) Yes, SQL Server *will* evaluate a.Type = 1 first. Sometimes. There's no guarantee, but in general when both of the statements evaluate to a numeric value no error will be thrown.

3) Still don't depend on it. If you absolutely must use a travesty of a data model that depends on a type to determine if another field is of a particular datatype, include the CAST statement.

Comment: Thanks for the info Wil.  I found both answers equally helpful, so I had to pick the first one in.  Thanks again!